# Find density function $f_{X}$ of $X$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

> Distribution function of random variable $X$ is: 
>   $$F(x) =  \begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ for } x<0 \\ x \mbox{ for } x \in (0,1) \\ 1 \mbox{ for } x \ge 1 \end{cases} $$
>   Find density function $f_{X}$ of $X$.

I am taking first steps with continuous random variables. It seems that $F(x)$ represents some kind of uniform distribution (continuous).
I know that $P(x \in A) = \int_A f_X(x) dx $ and $F_X(x) = P(X \le x)$ but how to use that in given simple case?

Comment: Try $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)$ as the anti-integral and note $F(x)$ is continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_X$ is simply the derivative of $F$. So $f_X(x)=1$ for $0<x<1$ and $0$ elsewhere. [This is the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$].

Comment: is that approach general? It is easy to use that if we deal with simple functions like in uniform distribution. But dealing with normal distribution wherein $F_X(x)$ are integrals,  it is much harder and seems to use another approach.

Comment: @Tester1998 You always differentiate the distribution function to get the density function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy *always* for an absolutely continuous distribution.  It does not work for discrete or singular distributions or mixtures of these

Comment: @Henry Sure, I was assuming the existence of $f_X$.

Answer (score 1):

The relation between the distributon function $F_X(x)$ and the densitiy function $f_X(x)$ is given by $F_X'(x)=f_X(x)$ in points of where $F_X$ is differentiable.

That means
$$f_X(x)=1_{(0,1)}$$
which is a uniform distribution.